# TableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath, How to catch a row name

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I fill my tableView with random data. So i don't know how many row i have and how to redirect it to screen i want to. I filled:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyClass *currentScreenElement = [self.tableRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:currentScreenElement.objectName];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:currentScreenElement.objectName];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = currentScreenElement.objectName;

    return cell;
}
```

And this works fine. I have a tableView with filled rows. Now i want to redirect to new screen and I doing it with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NewScreenClass *myScreen = [[NewScreenClass alloc] init];

    self.detailViewController = [[CreateView alloc] initWithScreenDef:[myScreen returnScreenFromName:@"second"]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Of course i know that what I actualy do here is create the same screen for every row. But how can i redirect to screen i want to?
My `currentScreenElement` object contains properties: `objectName` (display name in tableView) and `objectTarget` (screen definition). Both NSString.

And my question is should i save a my currentScreenElement to row patch somehow or maybe I should catch a objectName from dislay name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use the self.tableRows array again?

```
MyClass *currentScreenElement = [self.tableRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [currentScreenElement objectName];
```

It's the same thing you did to setup that row, just use it again.

Answer (score 3):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can get the cell by using

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Then just get the text from the cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text
```